# Running CeWL with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rr

I'm trying to run a Ruby program called [CeWL](http://www.digininja.org/projects/cewl.php).
I've added all of the required gems. When I try and open the .rb using ruby.exe it displays the message `missing url agrument (try --help)` and when I try to run it on `start cmd with ruby` or `start cmd with ruby on rails` I get the following:

```
CeWL 5.0 Robin Wood (robin@digininja.org) (www.digininja.org)
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:
36:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./cewl_lib (LoadError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/cewl/cewl.rb:90:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Read the error message... you are missing an argument. An argument is a command line option when running a command line application.

Comment: Navigate to the directory where the .rb file, in the command line. Once you are in that directory, execute `ruby <filename>.rb`. <filename> is whatever the file's name is that you are trying to execute. This will give you the same error again. The error means the program (ruby file) is expecting a url as an argument. You can specify arguments on the command line. If you just double-click the file, it will give the error as you are not passing the expected url.